# Get stdout in case of success and stdout+stderr in case of failure

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    logger.error('There was an error while ...: \n%s',
                 exc.output)
    raise
```

What is the easiest way to do the following:

1. Call a process using `subprocess` module.
2. If the program exited normally, put into `output` variable its standard output.
3. If the program exited abnormally, get its standard output **and** error.

Comment: Get both all the time. If there's no error, stderr will be empty, no?

Comment: I am running in a subprocess a PyQt4 application which spits messages like "Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. \n
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon"

Comment: Oh. Well, get both, and then if there's no error, just set stderr to nothing...

Comment: I would still recommend getting both all the time. If you're so certain that any errors you see when the return code is zero are known in advance and can be ignored, filter them out (which will allow you to see and debug any you weren't expecting) or just silently log them somewhere (which, again, might be helpful for debugging mysterious and unexpected problems.

Comment: If I do `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` `output` will contain both stadout+stderr, and I have to parse it to get the script output. Otherwise I have to pass my own file for stderr to get value of stderr. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Use a `stringIO` instance instead of a file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

process= subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait() #wait for the command to finish
output= process.stdout.read()
if process.poll(): #check the error code
    error= process.stderr.read()
```